# Converting mssql_escape_strings to sqlsrv escape strings

Tags: php, sql-server, string, escaping, sqlsrv

Okay I would first like to say I know nothing about php, I am just good at connecting dots, I am trying to convert a php script using mssql to sqlsrv, the first part was easy, mssql_close was just sqlsrv_close and so on, until I discovered this nasty beast: mssql_escape_string

Now for someone knowing nothing about this, and trying to turn this:

```
$username   = mssql_escape_string( $_POST['username'] );
$password   = mssql_escape_string( $_POST['password'] );
$password2  = mssql_escape_string( $_POST['password2'] );
$email  = mssql_escape_string( $_POST['email'] );
$email2 = mssql_escape_string( $_POST['email2'] );
$age    = mssql_escape_string( $_POST['age'] );

if ( strlen( $username ) > 25 || strlen( $username ) < 3 ) $errors[] = 'Username must be at least 3 characters long and no longer than 15 characters';
if ( preg_match( '[^A-Za-z0-9]' , $username) ) $errors[] = 'Username must be alphanumeric';

if ( strlen( $password ) > 15 || strlen( $password ) < 7 ) $errors[] = 'Password must be at least 7 characters long and no longer than 15 characters';
if ( $password != $password2 ) $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match';

if ( strlen( $email ) > 90 || strlen( $email ) < 5 ) $errors[] = 'Email must be at least 5 characters long and no longer than 90 characters';
if ( strpos($email, '@') == false) $errors[] = 'You have entered an invalid email address';
if ( $email != $email2 ) $errors[] = 'Emails do not match';

if ( strlen( $age ) > 2 || strlen( $age ) < 1 ) $errors[] = 'Age must be higher than 0 and no larger than 2 digits.';
if ( preg_match( '[^0-9]' , $age) ) $errors[] = 'Age may only contain numbers';
```

In to something like this(please note this is part of a different script that uses sqlsrv and I have no idea what it is really I just put the pieces together):

```
public function Escape( $str )
{
    $str = str_replace( "'", "''", $str );
    return trim( $str );
}
```

Without making the world implode would be next to impossible.

So I have no idea how to turn A in to B because it doesn't even look similar and I hope the fact that I got this far with no idea what any of it is, is enough to inspire some help :c

I can update with more of the script if need be, just ask, tried to keep it to specifics.

Comment: Use prepared statements. I've never used the sqlsrv driver so I can't advise too much on it. 1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php 2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296181(v=sql.105).aspx Alternatively, if you are just starting out PDO is available with SQL server. 3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628176(v=sql.105).aspx 4. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I'm afraid that actually doesn't help me, I don't know anything about php. :c I wouldn't know how to make those in to prepared statements

Comment: Use placeholders in place of the values (PHP variables). Look at example 3 on 4th link. For example I imagine one query you have is `select * from users where username = '$username';`. Prepared would be `select * from users where username = ?` then in the execute send the value. The driver will handle the quoting.

Comment: I'm reading and trying to understand it but it's not making any sense to me :/ I literally know nothing about php and trying to turn A in to a prepared statement just... doesn't make sense to me, I can't understand it lol

Comment: Post an example query you have an I'll post you a prepared example. Prepared statements aren't exclusive to PHP, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29.